# Как запустить анимацию по клику в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Есть 4 вида анимации для меню, созданы с помощью Anitamor в Unity

```
   anim1 (снизу в центр)
   anim2 (из центра вверх)
   anim3 (с верха в центр)
   anim4 (из центра вниз)
```

Первой пункт я уже сделал

1) анимация запускается, когда открываешь игру, `главное меню` выезжает `снизу в центр`

2) нужно сделать чтобы при клике, когда нажимаешь клавишу `Options` `главное меню` ехало вверх, а снизу в центр выезжало меню `Options`

3) Когда в `Options` нажимаешь `Back` опции должны ехать вниз, а сверху выезжает `Главное меню`

Как это реализовать в виде кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Если у вас через animation,то запускаем анимацию движения вверх по клику.

2.Если не через animation,то просто position меняем == двигаем вверх по оси по нажатию мыши за пределы видимости камеры и все.

официальная доументация

https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui

> официальный ролик о кнопках

здесь вся нужная инфа

https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button?playlist=17111

UPD: часть 2.Код.

- создаете новый скрипт
- добавляете скрипт на canvas

  ```
  public GameObject optionButton; // перетащить сюда кнопку
  public Animator m_Animator;  // перетащить сюда аниматор кнопки

  void Start()
  {
      m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();  
      optionButton.onClick.AddListener(goAnim);  
  }
  ```

  void goAnim()
  {
     m_Animator.Play("Name_your_anim");
  }

Comment: мне нужно через `animation` анимацию сделать, С видео ничего не понятно

Comment: @KillNoise tak?

Comment: А можно несколько аниматоров подключить и с каждого воспроизводить анимацию к примеру у меня на `MainMenu` и `Options`?

Comment: Animator один(тк это компонент),а анимаций сколь угодно много(имя в скобочках) PS если мой ответ помог,то отметьте его

Answer (score 1):

Давайте опишу структуру и общую логику :)

Для того, чтобы сделать вышеописанное у вас должны быть две панели-объекта. На каждой панели должен висеть собственный скрипт панели (например MenuPanel и OptionPanel) и Animator Contoller со своим аниматором.

Для каждой панели у вас должен быть создать свой аниматор со своими состояниями. В аниматоре из состояния enter переход в состояния Hide из Hide в Show из Show в Idle. Из Idle обратно в Hide.
Из состояния Hide в Show переход по триггеру Show и Idle в Hide по триггеру Hide. В сами эти состояния должны быть назначены нужные вам анимации (снизу в центр, из центра вверх и т.д. смотря, что вам нужно на панели, а в Idle - просто включение объекта панели, чтобы состояние не было пустым).

Можно создать вообще один аниматор - PanelAnimator, а потом добавлять перегруженные (override) (в них нужно перетащить тот, который будете менять и перетащить анимации, которые нужно заменить - с ним не придётся ещё раз настраивать связи).

У панелей должны быть специальные методы дли управления их показом или можно вообще сделать свойством. Например, такой вариант:

```
    [SerializeField]
    Animator _animator;

    public bool Visible
    {
        set
        {
            string trigger = value ? "Show" : "Hide";
            _animator.SetTrigger(trigger);
        }
    }
```

Здесь в сеттере проверяется какое значение нам пришло, если false  - выбирается левая строчка, если true, то, соответственно - правая. Затем эта строчка отправляется в аниматор, как триггер. А аниматор уже скрывает или показывает панель.

Соответственно, чтобы скрыть меню и показать настройки вам нужно будет сделать что-то вроде следующего:

```
    [SerializeField]
    MenuPanel _menuPanel;

    [SerializeField]
    OptionsPanel _opntions;

    void ClickReaction()
    {
        _menuPanel.Visible = false;
        _opntions.Visible = true;
    }
```

Ну, а как вы там получите доступ к экземплярам панели - это уже вопрос вашей архитектуры)

Это не лучший вариант организации UI, но реализует то, о чем вы спросили.

Соответственно, можете из панели Настроек подписаться на событие нажатия кнопки Option в панели Menu. И когда она будет нажата - вызвать метод, который выше я назвал ClickReaction.

Либо, вы можете в полях самой кнопки назначить, что она должна вызвать и у какой панели.

Comment: можете более подробнее)) эти две части кода в один скрипт, его вешать на `Canvas` и компонент `Animator` потом даем ссылки на эти меню, после чего в аниматор контролере создаем в `Parameters` переменную c названиям и типом `trigger` верно ? а дальше что ?

Comment: @KillNoise, нет-нет. Про аниматор вы правильно поняли, а про объекты - нет. У вас должен быть один канвас. Его чайлды - два объекта-панели. На каждом объекте-панели висит аниматор и экземпляр класса с первым кодом. Это нужно для того, чтобы панели анимировались раздельно. Вторая часть кода - это просто пример использования первого кода. Т.е. если вам нужно это в панели меню - добавляйте в код панели меню. Подписав сам метод на событие нажатия кнопки настроек.